# Where did my rings go?

Tags: nethack

I'm currently fighting my way through the castle in Nethack. I was wearing 2 rings when I reached this level (a ring of protection and a ring of regeneration), and after a long battle both my rings are simply gone. Everything else I was wearing/carrying is still with me (including some other rings).

I don't remember taking them off, and I'm positive I didn't fight any nymphs or inccubus/succubus. I'm a dwarven valkyrie (though I'm pretty sure it doesn't influence anything).

What could have happened to my rings?

Comment: Against what was the long battle?

Comment: @Tim: The ones I remember for sure were: many soldier/sergeants, several trolls, a couple different liches, a titan, a giant, and a few different elementals. I know there were one rust monster and one disenchanter, but I was paying very close attention to them, and I hadn't even fought them yet when I noticed the rings were gone. Beyond that, I think there were several different giant bugs, several "animals" (probably nagas and wolfs), and several meaningless undeads. It's the fight that happens right when you open the drawbridge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have reflection? Lightning can destroy rings that you are wearing. Sources of lightning that you're likely to have met include:

- Blue/chromatic dragon
- Wand of lightning
- Trapped chests

You could try to cycle through previous messages until you see something about your rings.

Comment: I tried cycling through previous messages, but it was too far back. I have shock resistance, but I did get zapped several times by a wand of lightning, so that's probably it.

Comment: To clarify, shock resistance has no effect whatsoever on rings and wands exploding; you need reflection to protect them. Going to the Castle without reflection is generally a Bad Idea.

Comment: @Wooble: Thanks, I've edited to reflect that mistake. Does reflection protect against chest traps?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither reflection nor shock resistance protects your wands and rings from chest traps. High luck, however, can.

Comment: Those chest traps are bad news, too.  I once lost the Castle wand of wishing when its chest exploded.  I did actually win that game, though almost wishless.  I tried going wishless out of spite after that incident, but Gods help me I had to wish for a cockatrice corpse on the Plane of Fire to get out of a mob.  Ah, good times.

Answer (score 5):

Was your Valkyrie throwing Mjollnir, the Valkyrie artifact weapon? Whenever you throw it, there is a 1/200 chance of it striking you upon returning. This can cause rings you're wearing to explode, even if you're shock resistant. I've definitely lost rings this way. See http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Mjollnir.

Comment: She was wielding an excalibur. But it's good to know that can happen.